# No data loaded from stored sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to access data from stored SQLite database. I've verified that the database has expected tables, which are not empty. Currently I have following code:

```
class DataClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
        MetaData(bind=self.engine).reflect()

        self.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session: Session = self.sessionmaker()
```

While I can list the table names using `self.engine.table_names()`, executing `self.session.query(Table).all()` where Table is declarative table definition, returns empty list, even though the table is not empty. Same thing happens with `self.engine.execute("select * from table").fetchall()`.

I feel like the metadata gets loaded, but not the data. Is there anything I missed? I couldn't find any further info about this.

Edit: table definition and creation

This is the part of code I use for recreating my database (only single table presented to be short).

```
class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(30))


def create_tables():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')

    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)

    record = Table(name="example string in a row")
    s: Session = session()
    s.add(record)
    s.commit()
```

After executing this part of code, I see that the database is recreated and table contains one row. But when trying to read data from existing database as stated above, empty list. (automap did not change this, but thanks for the recommendation in comments)

Comment: _I've verified that the database has expected tables, which are not empty_ How did you verify that they aren't empty?

Comment: Using database browser in Linux :)

Comment: Can you show how `Table` is defined?  Also, why not use [automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html) for this?